# Animating font size

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, catextlayer

Simple question: I have a `CATextLayer`. I want to make it bigger when I pinch it with a `CAAnimation` (any type you desire, prefer `CABasicAnimation`). How can I do this?

Note: can't use a simple `CABasicAnimation` with `transform.scale` as key, since if it is yes, resizes. but the text becomes terrible (not sharp at all). It's only an option if I can render the text while scaling. If this is possible, please help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the CATextLayer appear sharper as it scales up, increase its `contentsScale`. Don't overdo it, since you are demanding four times as much memory for every doubling of the scale.

(If this is a CATextLayer that you are creating yourself, you should have been setting its `contentsScale` at least to the screen resolution all along. The system does not do this for you.)

You might also like to use a scroll view, since it automatically does pinch-zooming for you. See the section of my book on [zooming with detail](http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_zooming_with_detail).

Comment: Thank you so much! But can you please tell me how to integrate the contentsScale property into a CABasicAnimation if possible? Thank you. (Yes the textLayer is self-made)

Comment: You don't need to integrate it. Just set it. Probably just setting it to 2 when you create it will be all you need! But seriously, consider using UIScrollView as shown in my book, since it makes this stuff a lot easier.

Comment: I'll consider it! Thank you for your help!